# Is it only sheep that have a 30-day period between their periods of acceptability as a korban?

Tags: korban, parah-adumah, maseches-parah

In [Parah 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Parah.1.3), we read:

> ‮כְּבָשִׂים, בְּנֵי שָׁנָה. וְאֵילִים, בְּנֵי שְׁתַּיִם. וְכֻלָּם מִיּוֹם לְיוֹם. בֶּן שְׁלשָׁה עָשָׂר חֹדֶשׁ אֵינוֹ כָשֵׁר לֹא לְאַיִל וְלֹא לְכֶבֶשׂ. רַבִּי טַרְפוֹן קוֹרֵהוּ פַּלְגָּס. בֶּן עַזַּאי קוֹרֵהוּ נוֹקֵד. רַבִּי יִשְׁמָעֵאל קוֹרֵהוּ פַּרְכָדִיגְמָא. [...]
>
> Lambs no more than one year old, And rams no more than two years old. And all these years are reckoned from day to day. One that is thirteen months old is not valid, neither as a ram nor as a lamb. Rabbi Tarfon called it palges. Ben Azzai called it noked. Rabbi Ishmael called it parakhrigma. [...]

We see that there is a 30-day period where the animal is considered neither a lamb nor a ram. This in-between period is *not* listed when discussing a cow in [Parah 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Parah.1.1).

Does the 30 day in-between period hold also for cows, even though it's not stated? If no, why is there such a distinction?

Comment: The Mishnah Acharonah on 1:3 asks this question, but I don't understand/can't parse the answer (if it is indeed an answer).

Comment: I don’t have time to write it up, but if someone wants to tackle Tosfos to RH 10a DH Ben and to BB 121a DH Yom, they address the general principle of יום אחד בשנה חשוב שנה and discuss how this discrepancy plays into that.

Answer (score 1):

The Artscroll [Yad Avraham commentary](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422600931.html) to this Mishna only discusses lambs and rams regarding this "indeterminate status". In addition, at no point in their commentary to the mishna in 1:1 (which describes the various appellations of a cow) do they discuss any intermediate 30-day period.

The Rambam also does not mention the intermediate status of cows ([Maase Korbanot 16:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1017028/jewish/Maaseh-Hakorbanot-Chapter-16.htm)).

Comment: Thanks. It's nice to see an answer (even if inferred by omission). Does the Artscroll commentary mention a "why"?

Comment: @magicker72 no and now I wonder myself :->